# Не выводится целое значение регистра al в MessageBox

Tags: ассемблер

Как вывести в MessageBox значение регистра `al`, чтобы оно равнялось 3? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none   

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data
mestitle db 'ООП Практичне заняття 6', 0

;message db 

lpOut db 255 dup(0)
lpFmtls db "%d  %d  %d  %d", 13, 10,
           "%d  %d  %d  %d", 13, 10,
           "BX = %d  AL = %d", 0

.data? 

.const

.code

start:

mov bx, 2
mov al, 3

invoke wsprintf,addr lpOut,addr lpFmtls, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,bx,al
invoke MessageBox, 0, ADDR lpOut, ADDR mestitle, MB_OK

end start
```

Comment: В 32-битном режиме параметры в функции WinAPI передаются через стек. В стек можно запушить только 32-битные (в том числе и регистры). Поэтому очищайте регистр eax перед записью в al (al - это часть регистра eax), потом в wsprintf передавайте eax целиком.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Очистка регистра перед записью решила проблему.